# Haskell lazy evaluation and let-in notation with infinite lists

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, infinite, let

Let `pack` be the function `[a] -> [[a]]` which takes a list and groups consecutive repeated elements into sublists.

Here are two implementations of `pack` in Haskell.

```
pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack x = reverse $ foldl f [] x where
  f cks@(ck1:_):rest) x
    | x == ck1 = (x:ck):rest
    | otherwise [x]:cks
  f _ x = [[x]]

pack' (x:xs) = let (first,rest) = span (==x) xs
  in (x:first) : pack' rest
pack' [] = []
```

These implementations have a critical semantic difference: the first implementation fails to terminate if we apply it to an infinite list, e.g. `[1..]`. *But the second implementation does work for infinite lists*. For example, `head $ pack' [1..]` evaluates.

My guess is the `let` `in` notation is lazy, hence `span` (which uses `let`-`in` in its Prelude definition) only evaluates finitely many expressions when we apply `pack'` on an infinite list.

However, this is an unsatisfactory explanation to me, because I can replace `reverse` with the following definition.

```
reverse' = foldl (\y x0 -> x0:y) []
```

If we do this, every expression in `pack` folds from left to right—so I would expect this to work for infinite lists—yet it still hangs.

**The question**: Why does `pack'` work for infinite lists and not `pack`?

Comment: You can not reverse an infinite list, since the first item of the reverse is the last item of the list, but there is never a last one. `foldl` can not work lazy, since it uses `f (f (f ... xn-2) xn-1) xn)` so the "outer" function works with the *last* value.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think this depends on how lists are implemented under the hood. In principle one only needs to reverse finitely many elements of a list in order to `pack` it. Therefore, I could rephrase the question as "why can't we reverse an infinite list?"

Comment: "why can't we reverse an infinite list?" is I would have thought an easy question to answer. Being able to work with infinite lists in Haskell basically means you can always figure out the first `n` elements for any positive integer `n` you could name. But what is the first element (never mind the first `n` elements) of `reverse [1..]`? Obviously that doesn't exist

Comment: @RobinZigmond I agree with you if List is implemented in the obvious inductive way. But this obvious way does not permit infinite lists, so Haskell (precisely GHC) is doing something nontrivial. I can imagine defining lists as the function type `Int -> a`, in which case reversing an infinite list is trivial.

Comment: But lists are implemented that simple way, and it does permit infinite lists. Eg `[1..]` can be implemented as `infinite :: [Int]; infinite = 1 : map (+1) infinite;`

Comment: @AnthonyD'Arienzo Let's play along and define `type List a = Int -> a`. Given that definition, how should I implement `reverse :: List a -> List a`? The only approach I can see needs to behave like it has a pattern clause reading `reverse xs 0 = xs infinity`, but of course there is no infinity index to use.

Comment: @amalloy, not to mention, the next step is `reverse xs 0 = xs $ infinity - 1`, but that isn't even sound in theory, let alone in practice.

Comment: @amalloy if lists are `Int -> a`, we have the traditional (right) cons operator `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, but we would also have a new left cons operator `L :: [a] -> a -> [a]`. We could then define `reverse` by flipping the left and right cons operators.

Comment: @RobinZigmond based on the comments in this thread, I think the (mathematically) nontrivial thing here is GHC lazily evaluates constructors, but `reverse` is strictly evaluated.

Comment: @AnthonyD'Arienzo I would still love to see an actual implementation. `L` is perfectly clear to me, but how do you use that to implement `reverse`? It should be pretty simple to write, right?

Comment: @AnthonyD'Arienzo what do you mean by "`reverse` is strictly evaluated?". On the one hand, `reverse undefined` will be `undefined`, which I guess makes it strict according to the strictest (no pun intended!) definition - but then any list function that pattern matches its argument (which is basically any other than constant functions) is then strict in that sense. But `head $ reverse [undefined, undefined, 1]` will come out quite uncomplainingly as `1` - ie `reverse` doesn't force evaluation of any list elements.

Comment: @amalloy let's call a two-sided list a TList, defined as `data TList a = Center | LCons (TList a) a | RCons a (TList a)`. Then `treverse :: TList a -> TList a` can be defined by `treverse Center = Center; treverse (RCons x0 xs) = LCons (treverse xs) x0; treverse (LCons xs x0) = RCons x0 (treverse xs)`. One can reverse infinite TLists **and reversing a reversed TList yields the original TList**.

Comment: Sure, you can reverse that structure - it's a slightly weird zipper for a list. It allows weird constructs like `LCons (RCons 1 (LCons Center 2)) Center)`, where right-then-left brings you to a different place than you started, but you could fix that by using the normal zipper type instead, which is also reversible. I was responding to your claim that it would be possible for lists represented as a function of type `Int -> a`, and I still don't think that can be done.

Comment: @amalloy I now agree with you there. I was working under the misconception that `TList a` is definably equivalent to `Int -> a`. I still wonder whether it's possible to define a 2-sided list and a `reverse'` for it so that the analogous `pack` evaluates for (right) infinite lists. I admit this would be contrived, and it doesn't help the original question since `[a]` is (naturally) 1-sided. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`foldl :: Foldable f => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) will for a given function `f`, and a base value `z` for a list `[x1, x2, …, xn]` produce the result of:

```
f (f (… (f (f z x1) x2) …) xn-1) xn
```

If we thus want to determine the *weak head normal form (WHNF)* we need to access the last element of the list. The fold function `f` of the `foldl` can be lazy in its first parameter, but we will at least have to make a function call with `xn` as parameter. This is why the [documentation on `foldl` says](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl):

> Note that to **produce the outermost application of the operator** the **entire input list** must be traversed. Like all left-associative folds, **`foldl` will diverge if given an infinite list**.

---

> My guess is the let in notation is lazy, hence span (which uses let-in in its Prelude definition) only evaluates finitely many expressions when we apply pack' on an infinite list.

You are correct, definitions in the `let`, `where` clauses and all other subexpressions are all lazy. But eventually if you are interested in the result, you need to determine the WHNF, and sometimes more than the WHNF.

The reason that it works is because [**`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) is implemented lazily. Indeed, `span` is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#span):

> ```
> span                    :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
> span _ xs@[]            =  (xs, xs)
> span p xs@(x:xs')
>          | p x          =  let (ys,zs) = span p xs' in (x:ys,zs)
>          | otherwise    =  ([],xs)
> ```

It thus does *not* need to know how the `span` of the tail looks in order to generate a 2-tuple where `x` that has satisfied the predicate is put in the first item, or in the second item if `p x` failed.

This thus means that `span` will generate a 2-tuple where the first item will contain all the elements that satisfy the predicate, whereas the second item is a lazy reference to the rest of the list to process.